# form_for icon outside of span

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue where I cannot change the submit button on a Rails form for an icon (specifically using ion icons however glyph icons also don't work);

The below image is what's occurring - the top search box is just HTML with the styled CSS and the second is the form for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Ed3.png

Below is the current code:

```
          <div class="row"><br>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div id="custom-search-input">
                      <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="search for foods" />
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                                  <i class="icon ion-ios-search nav-icon"></i>
                              </button>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Rails code below:

```
<div class="row"><br>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="custom-search-input">
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
              <%= form_tag nut_databases_path, method: :get do %>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:query], class: "form-control input-lg",  :placeholder => "search for foods", id: "query-alt", autocomplete: "off" %>
                  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-info btn-lg") do %>
                      <i class="icon ion-ios-search nav-icon"></i>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `span` tag in your erb markup is wrapping both the text_field_tag as well as the button_tag. Try rewriting it to only wrap the button tag, as in the pure HTML version above it, like so:

```
<div class="row"><br>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="custom-search-input">
      <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <%= form_tag nut_databases_path, method: :get do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:query], class: "form-control input-lg",  :placeholder => "search for foods", id: "query-alt", autocomplete: "off" %>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-info btn-lg") do %>
              <i class="icon ion-ios-search nav-icon"></i>
            <% end %>
          </span>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @Zoran - i changed like you suggested (I think you missed a , between the :button and :type - however now the icon has completely vanished

Comment: My mistake - I forgot to include the `<%=` to display that section. I noticed in your erb markup the `span` tag is in a different place than the pure HTML version, so I moved it down one level - that may have been causing the issue actually. Try using the new version of the code above and see if it does what's needed. Hope it's helpful to you!

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately for some reason it's still not working correctly, with the updated code its now appearing over two lines, image below

http://imgur.com/H7GDY5l